Remote and Local video call through JSSIP displays as Live Broadcast in IOS
I have an ionic cordova app and i implemented JSSIP to make video calls from users.
The current setup works great on android, but on IOS it shows both streams as live broadcast and i cannot view the simultaneously because i need to click the video for it to start playing.
The current setup is that the local video is positioned absolute on top of the remote video so that way the user can see both streams.
This is the current setup in HTML5:
  <div class="localVideo" *ngIf="localStreamReady === true"> <video poster="../../../../assets/svg/solid-grey.svg" #localVideo autoplay loop playsinline  style="height: -webkit-fill-available; border-radius: 11px;"></video> </div> <!-- Remote Video --> <div class="remoteVideo" *ngIf="remoteStreamReady === true"> <video poster="../../../../assets/svg/solid-grey.svg" #remoteVideo autoplay loop playsinline style="height: -webkit-fill-available;"></video> </div>
I tried the playsinline, transform: none, webkit-playsinline but nothing seems to work..
UPDATE
By adding <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" /> under platform ios.
Then in the video tag I added autoplay playsinline webkit-playsinline and it is working as expected now!
